# Permissions issue with script

Tags: permissions

I was trying to run a script to set my Oracle environment in RHEL. I ran it as `./foo.env`, but it wouldn't run because of a permissions issue. I then ran it as `. ./foo.env`, and it ran successfully. What's the difference between the two, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `./foo.env` means you're trying to execute the file as a shell script.  Running a file as a shell script means that the file must have executable permission for your account. Running `. ./foo.env` is the equivalent of `source ./foo.env`, which means you only need to have read permission to the file.